# Trigger set in Style not working as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml

I created a class library containing a style for almost every user control. In my applications i add this style library as a nuget package.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="tkButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource exQuiteDarkBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource tkLightGrayBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource TKTypeRegular}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource tkMediumGrayBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="60"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource tkBrandBlueBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource tkBrandBlueBrush}"/>            
            </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource tkMediumGrayBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource tkDarkGrayBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The library contains for example a simple button. In most Usercontrols i use a trigger
for the `IsMouseOver` Property to change some colors.
In my Application I'm using the style like this:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource tkButton}" Content="button with ITALIC and BOLD type" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}"/>
<Button BorderBrush="{StaticResource tkRedBrush}" Style="{DynamicResource tkButton}" Content="button with ITALIC type" FontStyle="Italic" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}"/>
```

The first button adds the style and works as expected when hovering over it.
The second one uses the style, but changes the `BorderBrush` to red. When hovering over the second Button i expect to change the `BorderBrush` but it stays red.

The only solution i can imagine is to set the trigger inside the window/application again.
Are there any different solutions to change this behavior?

Comment: `BorderBrush="{StaticResource tkRedBrush}"` declaration has higher precedence, than style

Comment: Yes i know. But is it possible to give the trigger a higher precedence inside the style or is there no way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the trigger to the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource tkBrandBlueBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

If you put it in the `Style`, the local value specified by `BorderBrush="{StaticResource tkRedBrush}"` will take precedence over the value set by `Setter`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence

Comment: I changed my `ControlTemplate` and removed my `Style.Triggers`, but your suggestion doesn't work. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Romox: Sorry, you should also give the `Border` element in tempate a name and refer to that name using the `TargetName` property of the `Setter`. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to declare your button on the following way, by inheriting `tkButton` style and overriding the `BorderBrush` value, because `BorderBrush="{StaticResource tkRedBrush}"` has higher precedence than style declaration

```
<Button Content="button with ITALIC type" FontStyle="Italic" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource tkButton}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource tkRedBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: This actually works, but you have to be carefull with `BasedOn`: It only allows a`StaticResource` and you will not be able to change it during runtime. So in the case of my style library it's not a 100% solution because i have to themes and i'm able to switch between those when using DynamicResource

Comment: Yes, you are right regarding `DynamicResource`, updated an answer, because written it by hand